# No native ExpoFirebaseCore module found, are you sure the expo-firebase-core module is linked properly?

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

Since that I'm using the package  **"expo-firebase-recaptcha": "^2.3.1"**, everytime I run the application with expo start, I receive this warning :

> WARN  No native ExpoFirebaseCore module found, are you sure  the
> expo-firebase-core module is linked properly?
> at RootRouteNodeProvider (http://192.168.1.19:19000/inde x.ts.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:111237:23)
> at ContextNavigator (http://192.168.1.19:19000/index.ts. bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:116052:24)
> at RNCSafeAreaProvider
> at SafeAreaProvider (http://192.168.1.19:19000/index.ts. bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:105019:24)
> at RNGestureHandlerRootView
> at GestureHandlerRootView
> at GestureHandler
> at ExpoRoot (http://192.168.1.19:19000/index.ts.bundle// &platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:116039:24)
> at App
> at withDevTools(App) (http://192.168.1.19:19000/index.ts .bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127358:27)
> at ErrorToastContainer (http://192.168.1.19:19000/index. ts.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:127282:24)
> at ErrorOverlay
> at RCTView
> at View (http://192.168.1.19:19000/index.ts.bundle//&pla tform=android&dev=true&hot=false:48534:43)
> at RCTView
> at View (http://192.168.1.19:19000/index.ts.bundle//&pla tform=android&dev=true&hot=false:48534:43)
> at AppContainer (http://192.168.1.19:19000/index.ts.bund le//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:48411:36)
> at main(RootComponent) (http://192.168.1.19:19000/index. ts.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:84925:28)     LOG
> onAuthStateChanged: false

I've seen that many people encounter this issue too, but none of the solution helped any of us. I'm using Expo SDK 48.
And yet, I've installed those packages :

> ```
> "expo-firebase-core": "^6.0.0",
> "expo-modules-core": "^1.2.7",
> ```

Comment: Also here to see if anyone found a reason / fix for this warning

Answer (score 3):

`expo-firebase-recaptcha` rely internally on `expo-firebase-core`, and since both libraries are deprectaed in Expo SDK 48, the native modules have been removed from the Expo GO client.

You can migrate to [React Native Firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/) to access the supported version.

Answer (score 1):

I have lost my mind trying to get rid of that warning on the last days, without losing the benefits and features that `expo-firebase-recaptcha` provides. What I ended up doing is creating a **patch** with `yarn v2+` (I have version 4).

Here is the patch that does not use `expo-firebase-core` anymore:

https://gist.github.com/JMRMEDEV/7d18e354c320e463001d2d2a73218b8f

Follow these steps:

- Have `yarn` version `2` or above (I use `4.0.2`).
- Have `expo-constants` package in your `node-modules`. If you haven't done already, add it to your project.
- Create this directory in the root of your project (if you don't have already): `.yarn\patches`.
- Inside of `.yarn\patches`, create a file called `expo-firebase-recaptcha-npm-2.3.1-6b374029cd.patch` (I guess you can rename it as you please, as long as you reference it in your `package.json`) and fill it with the content of https://gist.github.com/JMRMEDEV/7d18e354c320e463001d2d2a73218b8f.
- On your `package.json` reference the package from the patch: `"expo-firebase-recaptcha": "patch:expo-firebase-recaptcha@npm%3A2.3.1#~/.yarn/patches/expo-firebase-recaptcha-npm-2.3.1-6b374029cd.patch"`
- Perform `yarn install` on your project once more.

And vualá, you should have got rid of the annoying warning and keep the original package functionality. Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you for your patch! that saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Github Issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/7781#issuecomment-1686589559), you don't need to use `expo-firebase-recaptcha`. It's just a WebView and you can replace it easily.

You can see the [replacement written by maksof-sarwar](https://github.com/maksof-sarwar/expo-firebase-recaptcha-patch) for detailed implementation.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your patch! that saved a lot of time.
-> I had troubles to upgrade yarn to version 2 so I have modified your patch to use npx patch-package tool
this way we can stick at yarn version 1 or npm

instructions:

- create a file inside the patches dir: `patches/expo-firebase-recaptcha+2.3.1.patch`
- put this file contents inside:
  https://gist.github.com/EKoetsjarjan/1a4457c763e240f1324bf4ff60d5391a
- after that you can add postinstall inside your package.json file.

`"postinstall": "npx patch-package"`

- or run `npx patch-package` from your terminal directly to test it.